# two selectors on click event to change button text

Tags: jquery, html

i have a FAQ script that uses dl, dt. dd :

```
$('.faqs dd').hide(); // Hide all DDs inside .faqs
$('.faqs dt').hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('hover' , 'slow')},function(){
        $(this).removeClass('hover' , 'slow')}).click(function(){ 
        // Add class "hover" on dt when hover
        $(this).next().slideToggle('normal'); // Toggle dd when the respective dt is clicked
    });
```

the html looks like this :

```
<dl class="faqs">
    <dt>question 1 <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs pushme">open answer</button></dt>
    <dd>answer 1</dd> 
</dl>
```

although clicking on the question opens the answer i want to add the button. (because the questions are long and i'm not sure the user will know he/she needs to click the question).

what i'm trying to do is to change the buttons text from 'open' to 'close' acording to the state of the dd or by a click event that is shared by the buttons class and the dt.
i've tried :

```
$('.faqs dt, .pushme').click(function () {
    $('.pushme').text(function(i, v){
        return v === 'open' ? 'close' : 'open'
    })
});
```

but that worked only on the first selector (.facs dt)
I've also tried checking if the dd is display:none/block and changing the buttons with .html() but that didnt work out for me.

anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to target the `pushme` element which is inside the current faq, so try

```
$('.faqs dd').hide(); // Hide all DDs inside .faqs
$('.faqs dt').hover(function () {
    $(this).addClass('hover', 'slow')
}, function () {
    $(this).removeClass('hover', 'slow')
}).click(function () {
    $(this).next().stop(true, true).slideToggle('normal');
    $(this).find('.pushme').text(function (_, text) {
        return text == 'open answer' ? 'close answer' : 'open answer'
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/p4Bn6/)

Comment: not i'll try to push it a bit.. :) if i want to also to toggle the buttons class : $(this).toggleClass('.success'); ?

Comment: yeh, i fixed that error but it still does not work. i've tried changing places

Comment: @fafchook can you try to replicate the problem in the fiddle

Comment: ok go it :  $(this).find('.btn-primary').toggleClass('btn-success'); thanks so much for your time :)